# First child CSS table troubles

Tags: css, css-tables

I've seen a few other questions about first child stuff but I can't seem to be able to get anything to work.
I have a table and want the first column to be all bold but the rest of the text to be normal.

About the tables I have:

```
div.article table{ 
    /* formatting stuff */
}

div.article table th {
    /* formatting */
}

div.article table tr {
    /* more formatting. I've got a funky looking table. */
}
```

So then I try:

```
div.article table tr:first-child {
    font-style:bold;
}
```

but it doesn't seem to have an impact.

Any ideas? I suspect it's something really small but I'm overlooking it.

Comment: Can you show part of your html as well?

Answer (score 4):

You should use:

```
div.article table tr td:first-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

With the way you have it set up currently you are specifying that the row which is the `first-child` of the `table` should have its `font-style` set to `bold`. There are 2 problems there, you should be using `font-weight` instead of `font-style`, and you are wanting to target all `td`'s which are the `first-child` of their row.

Comment: It's font weight and not font style

Comment: oh god. font-weight/style. that was the stupid little small thing *sinks into the ground*

Comment: That's not the only problem, if you want to target first column you have to change it to `div.article table tr td:first-child` as specified in the answer.